# How to change where the confirmation email is sent

Tags: email

Currently when a member signs up, the email goes through to our generic head office email and is copied in to a member of staff.  How do I change the member of staffs email?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Contributions -> Manage Contribution Pages, choose the relevant page, and then click on Configure, all  the way over on the right. Then take a look at Receipt for that page, 
might be at 
`https://[your_website]/civicrm/admin/contribute/amount?action=update&reset=1&id=1`
and the e-mail addresses that a receipt is cc'd and bcc'd to.

[image: ContribReceipt]

Answer (score 1):

Another place these 'send email to x' may be hiding is in the Adv Settigs of the Profile that is used on the Contribution page (if 'sign up' is indeed a contribution page